# Problem: Play Store charging money to an App tester

Tags: android, testing

I have an Android app which has a suscription system (it works. I'm already earning some cents).
I have defined some testers for it, so that they can use and test the full app.
The problem is that some of them are asked to pay in the normal way.

When I try it in my device, I have a test card that I can use in order to get the suscription without paying any money. I even have the option to choose between a card that always works and another one that allways fails. Everything is as stated in the documentation.

I have added their emails on the list. They are recognised as testers. Yet they are asked to pay.

I don't know why these other testers don't get the same cards for payment.
Am I forgeting something?

Thanks for your help!